# Как в цикле построчно читать csv файл и после смены кодировки записывать в другой?

Tags: python

Подскажите как построчно читать файл в одной кодировке и записывать в другой файл в нужной кодировке. Есть рабочий код, который работает на небольших файлах, но у меня есть ряд файлов по 7 гб и ноут зависает при запуске кода.
Код следующий:

```
file_old = open('C:\\Users\\Desktop\\files\\file_old.csv', mode=r, encoding='utf-16le')
file_new = open('C:\\Users\\Desktop\\files\\file_new.csv', mode=w, encoding='utf-8')
text = file_old.read()
file_new.write(text)
```

Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Какие конкретные трудности? в использовании цикла for? в использовании сторонних библиотек или просто хотите, чтоб задачу решил вам кто-то другой?

Comment: Трудность в том, что я не знаю python. По работе нужны файлы в другой кодировке. Можете не решать мне эту задачу и пройти мимо. Мне что в своем вопросе нужно было описать свой бэкграунд?

Comment: Посмотрите ваши вопросы за прошлый год, у вас есть скрипт читающий csv  файл построчно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так:

```py
with open('C:\\Users\\Desktop\\files\\file_old.csv', mode='r', encoding='utf-16le') as file_old,
     open('C:\\Users\\Desktop\\files\\file_new.csv', mode='w', encoding='utf-8') as file_new:
    for text in file_old: # читаем построчно
        file_new.write(text) # пишем прочитанное
```